# Changing/Replacing text inside a PDF using Java

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

Any clue about a good library to programmatically produce a PDF in Java, using a PDF as a template?

Answer (score 7):

try iText. It has many many goodies. There is also a book about it by Manning [iText in Action](http://www.manning.com/lowagie/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to edit the Text in the template, you should set up the template carefully and use forms for text content. You can't easily replace text in PDFs because they do not contain text structure.

There is a blog article highlighting some of the issues at http://pdf.jpedal.org/java-pdf-blog/bid/17370/Problems-editing-PDF-files

Comment: Link is dead - a more current link seems to be http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2009/05/problems-editing-pdf-files/